# Ionic FirebaseX getToken() not return any data

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic4, cordova-plugin-firebasex

I start connecting Firebase Cloud Messaging to Ionic + Angular, but when I call method `const token = await this.firebase.getToken();` I don't get anything. Application keeps working, but I still don't get the token. Full code:

```
async getToken() {
  const hasPermission = await this.firebase.hasPermission();
  if (Capacitor.getPlatform() === 'ios' && !hasPermission) {
    await this.firebase.grantPermission();
  }

  const token = await this.firebase.getToken();
  this.saveToken(token);
}
```

I added GoogleService-Info.plist to the root of my app:

[image: GoogleService-Info.plist]

In addition, in my firebase account I already upload my *APNs Auth Key* and I created certificates on AppleDeveloper Acc. The application identificator the same in Apple, Application and Firebase.

What I did wrong?

Comment: How you added GoogleService-info.plist in project? Manually copy paste from file system?

Comment: @PareshGami I download it from Firebase and paste to the project

Comment: I have the exactly same problem.. did you solve it?